# How do I display the pipenv workspace while still having a custom PROMPT_COMMAND?

Tags: bash, pipenv

By default, when I enter a pipenv shell, the start of my prompt indicates the workspace in which I'm working.

```
user@user-dsktp:~/main$ pipenv shell
Spawning environment shell (/bin/bash). Use 'exit' to leave.
user@user-dsktp:~/main$ . /home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/main-GqtUWnwk/bin/activate
(main-GqtUWnwk) user@user-dsktp:~/main$
```

However, if I customise my prompt (to display git information):

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]" "\n\\\$ "'
```

I lose the workspace information:

```
user@user-dsktp:~/main (develop=)
$ pipenv shell
Spawning environment shell (/bin/bash). Use 'exit' to leave.

user@user-dsktp:~/main (develop=)
$ . /home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/main-GqtUWnwk/bin/activate

user@user-dsktp:~/main (develop=)
$
```

Does anyone know how to get it back? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [GNU Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-PROMPT_005fCOMMAND):

> If set, the value is interpreted as a command to execute before the printing of each primary prompt (`$PS1`).

In your case, you run a function `__git_ps1` with parameter `"\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\W\[\033[00m\]" "\n\\\$ "` before `$PS1` is print.

What is `__git_ps1`? That depends on your environment (it is not a standard Bash function), but it is a help function that produces a PS1 with Git information. You can see what it is with

```
$ type __git_ps1
```

If you look into the source, you may find `__git_ps1` *overwrites* the default PS1. This is why the virtual environment name is not shown. The virtual environment’s name, as @chepner mentioned, is displayed via the `activate` script by modifying your `PS1`. `__git_ps1`, however, overwrites that change.

The way to fix it once and for all is to learn some Bash, and try to craft a better `PROMPT_COMMAND` :) Or you can use this instead

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='
  __PS1_SUFFIX="\\\$ "
  if [[ -n "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]]; then
    __PS1_SUFFIX="($(basename "$VIRTUAL_ENV")) $__PS1_SUFFIX"
  fi
  __git_ps1 "\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]" "\n$__PS1_SUFFIX"
'
```

This snippet checks if `VIRTUAL_ENV` is set (this would point to the virtual environment’s root if set by virtualenv), and adds its name to the second line of the prompt (befure `$`). Now this is not the best way to do it because the directory name does not always match the prompt, but it should work for you right now. You can decide yourself whether to descend deeper into this Bash script abyss if you ever find this snippet insufficient for your use case.

Answer (score 2):

The `activate` script just has something roughly equivalent to

```
PS1="$(basename "$VIRTUAL_ENV") $PS1"
```

to add the virtual environment to the prompt. You can simply add the same
command substitution to your own prompt definition.

Your `PROMPT_COMMAND` most likely overwrites anything `activate` does to the prompt, but to avoid any nasty surprises, you can set `VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT` to any non-empty string to prevent `activate` from touching your prompt at all.